# how to convert javascript time object to different format?

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
    tableHTML += "<td class=\"stamp\">"+jsonObject[i]['stamp']+"</td>";
```

this is currently displaying `2012-05-25 23:08:57`how can i change this to a `May 25,2012`

a commentor noted that it may be better to do this with php, the only time i could do it with php is before entering it to the array. is this possible?

```
$videos_array = array();
while ($i < $num) {
$current_video = array (
'stamp'=>mysql_result($result,$i,"stamp"));
array_push($videos_array, $current_video);
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($videos_array);
```

Comment: Is this something you are receiving from a php page? it may be better to do this server side

Comment: if i did it with php, i would need to convert it prior to entering it into the array? i edited my question above, if you know how to convert it with php, prior to entering it into the array, let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure that formatting dates in PHP is the right way to go.  It is best to think of dates as data.  It is true in JSON that you have to have to have rendered in some format, and ISO 8601 is pretty much the world's new standard.  So if you are getting the date string `2012-05-25 23:08:57` from PHP, wait until the last second to  format it in JavaScript.  You code will be easier to internationalize, assuming you want to display dates in other locales....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a real date library as Dr.Dredel suggests, but if you want an awful hack, there is always

```
new Date(Date.parse("2012-05-25 23:08:57")).toDateString().substring(4)
```

Not to be used in serious code.  It relies on the output of `toDateString` which is locale dependent.  The proper way to do this is to take a date object and just before you are to display it, choose a *date format*.

The built-in date object in JavaScript does not do a good job of this.

You can find examples of its use in [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

**ADDENDUM**

Okay, I've gotten serious and produced an example using datejs.  You can find a live working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kd9G6/).

Basically, put the following in your HTML:

```
<script src="http://cachedcommons.org/cache/datejs/1.0.0/javascripts/date-min.js"></script>
```

​
Then in your JavaScript adapt the following code:

```
var d = Date.parse("2012-05-25 23:08:57");
alert(d.toString("MMM dd, yyyy"));
```

​

Comment: ok i downloaded the real date library, but i have not idea how to use it. i just include it on my page, and then what?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show a usage of datejs.  It _is_ a very nice library, even though it doesn't appear to have been updated in years.  I'm not too familiar with other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using Date.js http://www.datejs.com/ though obviously for something this simple you could roll your own pretty quickly.